# I felt my code is not exactly right, but I don't know what's wrong

Tags: r

The question is:
Simulate a function to roll a dice. Note that a dice turns up with numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 or 6. The function should do the following: you roll the dice twice, and if both the numbers are the same then return ‘You Win’ otherwise return ‘You Lose’ (hint: use sample())
my code is:

```
s <- function(x)
{
    x = 1:6
    s1 <- sample(x, size = 1, replace = TRUE)
    s2 <- sample(x, size = 1, replace = TRUE)
    result <- ifelse(s1 == s2, "You Win", "You Lose")
    return(result)
}
s(5)
```

Even if the code is right, is there a more effective way to write it? I think it's a little bit tedious.

Comment: You can't run it to find out if it's right?

Comment: The x input parameter in your function doesn't do anything, since you assign 1:6 to x on the first line anyway.

Comment: Do you really need `replace=TRUE` on a length 1 sample?

Comment: Looks about right. I suppose you could just sample once.. Let's say you want to simulate the experiment 100 times. You could do `n<-100; x<-sample(1:6, 2*n, replace=TRUE); result<-ifelse(x[seq(1,(2*n-1),by=2)] == x[seq(2, 2*n, by=2)], "WIN","LOSE")` You have a few more questions I've seen before, and I think you're just starting to learn R, that's good, you should learn about the vectorized operations.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

less tedious? probably not, but less repitition

```
rolldice <- function() {
  sample(1:6, size = 1)
}

s <- function()
{
  ifelse(rolldice() == rolldice(), "You Win", "You Lose")
}
s()
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using sample() you can also use runif() with round() functions for your requirement where you don't have to give x explicitly.

```
rolladice <- function(){
  s1 <- round(runif(1,1,6))
  s2 <- round(runif(1,1,6))
  result <- ifelse(s1 == s2, "You Win", "You Lose")
  return(result)
}
```

Hope this will solve your issue.